# Installing Windows XP x86 from a non-bootable disc

Tags: windows-xp, installation, bootable-media

I have a genuine Windows XP x86 SP3 downloaded from MS Website (Partners) but this CD is not bootable when trying to fresh-install it. The autorun works fine when I put it in my DVD reader but can't install it on any computer.

I'm trying to find a way, with a bootdisk to have it installed but for any reason (Might be n00b) I just can't make a proper NTFS boot disk and have that CD to run for a clean installation.

I know this is an easy question but I need a little help.

Comment: How often have you tried booting the CD, I've had similar problems on an old laptop and it just took me quite some tries to get it booting

Comment: I tried it on 3 different laptops (Toshiba, Dell and HP) and all of them failed to boot with. Also tried on Dell and HP workstations without any luck.

Comment: Make sure you boot using the lowest speed your drive can handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you changed the BIOS so it includes the optical drive in it's boot sequence?

**UPDATE**

From your other comments it appears that the CD is not bootable. You'll need to re-burn it.

Comment: Yes but no luck with that one too... but it's a CD, not a DVD

Comment: I'm re-burning it at the moment. I'll keep ya posted.

Comment: I burned to CD. One with Roxio, from the downloaded file from Microsoft. No Luck. The other one, I used the bootfont.bin as the bootable file. no luck again. I see a little dash flickering when loading from the CD and it's stuck there.

Comment: After this "Pain-in-the-ass" process, we finally decided to buy a brand new Windows XP Pro CD from MS.

Answer (score 1):

If you CD is not bootable for some reason, you can always create your own installation disk as long as you have the installation source files (i386 folder), here's a guide that explains the procedure step-by-step-:

**[How to Create a Bootable Windows XP Setup Disk on a Preinstalled / Preloaded Windows System](http://www.howtohaven.com/system/createwindowssetupdisk.shtml)**

Comment: So far I will try this one: http://webolio.wordpress.com/2007/03/20/installing-windows-xp-using-a-non-bootable-cd-and-no-floppy-disks/

Comment: @r0ca - way too complicated :) this method was used for old computers without CDROM drive and no option to boot from USB, however, it works ... extremely slow without SMARTDRV though. :)

Comment: I'm trying this one right now.

Answer (score 0):

the boot disk doesn't need to be NTFS.  Can you elaborate on how you burned that CD-ROM?  Did you download an .ISO file?  What burning tool did you use?

As ChrisF suggested, I believe it can be fixed with a change in your BIOS.

Comment: I downloaded it from Microsoft website. We download our software from there since we have a business partnership with them. So, I downloaded an .ISO file, burned it with Nero (as I usualy do) but this time, that CD just won't boot...

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a tutorial to making a bootable CD:](http://www.trap17.com/index.php/windows-installation-disk-bootable_t68355.html)

> You will need to get the boot sector
>   files, which you can get [from
>   here](http://www.nu2.nu/download.php?sFile=wxp10.zip).  Open the zip and browse to
>   cds\winxppro\files (or
>   cds\winxphome\files), copy w2ksect.bin
>   to C:\ (you can copy to another
>   location but in that case you will
>   need to adjust some parameter).
>
> Copy all the files on your
>   non-bootable CD to one folder, for
>   example C:\winxpinst (if you have more
>   than one cd/dvd drive you don't need
>   to do this, you can copy straight from
>   the second cd drive).
>
> Download and install [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/)
>   which is a free utility to burn
>   files/images to CD. We will now create
>   a script to be imported in ImgBurn, to
>   do so open a text editor (e.g.
>   Notepad) and paste the following:
>
> ```
> [START_BACKUP_OPTIONS]
> BuildMode=1
> Destination=0
> TestMode=0
> Verify=1
> WriteSpeed=0
> Copies=0
> FileSystem=1
> PreserveFullPathnames=0
> RecurseSubdirectories=1
> IncludeHiddenFiles=1
> IncludeSystemFiles=1
> IncludeArchiveFilesOnly=0
> AddToWriteQueueWhenDone=0
> ClearArchiveAttribute=0
> VolumeLabel_ISO9660=VRMHOEM_EN
> VolumeLabel_Joliet=
> VolumeLabel_UDF=
> Identifier_System=
> Identifier_VolumeSet=
> Identifier_Publisher=
> Identifier_Preparer=
> Identifier_Application=
> Dates_FolderFileType=0
> Restrictions_ISO9660_InterchangeLevel=0
> Restrictions_ISO9660_AllowMoreThan8DirectoryLevels=1
> Restrictions_ISO9660_AllowMoreThan255CharactersInPath=1
> Restrictions_ISO9660_AllowFilesWithoutExtensions=1
> Restrictions_ISO9660_AllowFullASCIICharacterSet=1
> Restrictions_ISO9660_DontAddVersionNumberToFiles=1
> Restrictions_Joliet_InterchangeLevel=1
> Restrictions_Joliet_AllowFilesWithoutExtensions=1
> Restrictions_Joliet_AddVersionNumberToFiles=0
> BootableDisc_MakeImageBootable=1
> BootableDisc_MediaEmulationType=0
> BootableDisc_BootImageFile=C:\w2ksect.bin
> BootableDisc_DeveloperIdentifier=
> BootableDisc_LoadSegment=07C0
> BootableDisc_LoadSectorCount=4
> [END_BACKUP_OPTIONS]
>
> [START_BACKUP_LIST]
> C:\winxpinst
> [END_BACKUP_LIST]
> ```
>
> Be sure to change:
>
> ```
> BootableDisc_BootImageFile=C:\w2ksect.bin
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> [START_BACKUP_LIST]
> C:\winxpinst
> ```
>
> to the locations where you copied the
>   w2ksect.bin file and you stored the
>   Windows installation files (can be the
>   cd drive letter if you are using two
>   cd drives). Then save the file as
>   some-name.ibb (important, make sure
>   windows does not add a txt extension
>   to the file name).
>
> If you have installed ImgBurn you can
>   double-click this file and the program
>   will open with the right
>   configuration. At this point you only
>   have to hit "Burn" or similar command
>   in the program and the bootable cd
>   will be created. The installation
>   files will also be copied to the cd.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely with your computer; I don't think Microsoft has ever created a non-bootable XP CD. Try booting the computer to a known bootable CD, such as Knoppix.

If the CD really isn't bootable, you can make a bootable one using nLite.

Comment: I'm really this CD is not bootable since I tried it on several computers, DVD/CD drives. Maybe I need to re-burn it

Answer (score 0):

Just create a boot floppy. Use it to boot into the machine. Then restart the machine. Set the BIOS boot option to Floppy. Then boot using it. Move to (CDROM Drive):\WINNT\setup.exe

Comment: There is no WINNT directory on Windows XP installation CD.